# How to update MySQL database table cell based on the values in other cell

Tags: mysql

I've this MySQL database table called "DataField". It has an incrementing Primary Key column called "ID", another column called "Name" and another column called "LocType". What I would like to do is, as soon as the ID and Name fields are updated in the "DataField" table I would like to also update the "LocType" table automatically with value "1".

Can someone explain me how to do this?

Comment: I can explain but unfortunately I don't know the exact code for it. What you need to do is to handle the event that the database receives when a row is updated, and when that event is triggered get the row, find out if the values you're wanting to check have been updated, and if they are you can use the index to make the change to the row.

Comment: Are you talking about TRIGGER ?

Comment: I believe so, apologies for the above, I accidentally pressed return. What language are you using interact with MySQL?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please verify if the below code I provided is correct?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Trigger to achieve this. Try something like the following code,

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_LOC_TYPE
    BEFORE UPDATE ON DataFiled
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE LocTYPE
    SET Field_Name = 'New Value';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please verify if the below code is correct?


CREATE TRIGGER DataField_Trig
AFTER INSERT ON DataField 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO DataField(LocType) VALUES("1")

Comment: You will have much less trouble of you wrapt your trigger inside a IF( NOT(@trigger_disabled) ) call. Otherwise every maintenance import/export/update will also trigger this one and maybe corrupt your data.